# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

When I call /buy with "GET" method I come across this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'

## buy.html: template file

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
 Buy
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('buy') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" 
                 name="symboll" placeholder="Symbol" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus 
                name="number" placeholder="number of share" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn-default btn" type="submit"> Buy </button>
            </div>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

### application.py:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
   if request.method == "GET":
       return render_template("buy.html")
```

Comment: Can you print the whole stack trace, or provide layout.html, please? It's possible that the missing % is in layout.html.

Comment: ok I will print it @JakeConway

Comment: You should edit those into the main post itself - Stack Overflow requires that all post "answers" be solutions to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your error raised in `login.html` or something like that. Look for the error in the template, rendered by your `login_required` decorator.

Comment: the login code is the same as the code of buy.html ,I don't understand what's wrong in my code

Comment: Could you provide full stack-trace message ?